# Increase count of item for a customer

Tags: c++

Hello I do a shopping list. I have a class Customer and a class Item. My program work like this, I ask the name of the customer if the customer isn't in the database I add this customer, and if the customer is I print an error in order to say that the customer exists. After that I print a list of 10 products, and ask the customer to choose a product and increase the count of the specific Item for this customer.
My program don't give any error, I try do debug but I don't find the error, because the program doesn't increase the count of anything.

This is my function in my main:

```
void DisplayList(Item shopList[10], Customer& custom)
{
    int choose_item = 1;
    while (choose_item != 0)
    {
        cout << "The items you can buy are: (0 to exit)" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cout << i + 1 << ". " << shopList[i].getName() << "  " << shopList[i].getUnitPrice() << "  x" << shopList[i].getCount() << endl;
        }
        cout << "What item you would like to buy, Input: ";
        cin >> choose_item;
        custom.addItem(shopList[choose_item - 1]);
    }
}
```

My customer header:

```
class Customer
{
public:
    Customer(string);
    Customer(){}
    void addItem(Item);
    set<Item> getItems() const;

private:
    string _name;
    set<Item> _items;


};
```

My customer cpp

```
Customer::Customer(string name)
{
    _name = name;
}
Customer::Customer(){  };


void Customer::addItem(Item SpecificItem)
{
    set<Item>::iterator it;
    if ((it = _items.find(SpecificItem)) != _items.end())
    {
        SpecificItem.setCount(SpecificItem.getCount() + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        _items.insert(SpecificItem);
    }

}
set<Item> Customer::getItems() const
{
    return _items;
}
```

My item header:

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item(string, string, double);
    ~Item();

    //get and set functions
    string getName() const;
    string getSerialNumber() const;
    int getCount();
    double getUnitPrice() const;

    void setCount(int count);


private:
    string _name;
    string _serialNumber; //consists of 5 numbers
    int _count; //default is 1, can never be less than 1!
    double _unitPrice; //always bigger than 0!

};
```

My item cpp

```
#include "Item.h"

Item::Item(string name, string serial_number, double price) : _name(name), _serialNumber(serial_number), _unitPrice(price), _count(1)
{
};

Item::~Item(){};

string Item::getName() const
{
    return _name;
}

string Item::getSerialNumber() const
{
    return _serialNumber;
}

int Item::getCount()
{
    return _count;
}

double Item::getUnitPrice() const
{
    return _unitPrice;
}

void Item::setCount(int count)
{
    _count = count;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, you should not print an error that a customer exists in the database.  You can print the fact, but don't make it an error.

Comment: Don't use arrays.  Use `std::vector` instead.  With arrays, you need to pass the capacity along also.

Comment: No the exercice is to use array, so I can't do this

Comment: "This is my code in `main`:" - `void DisplayList(...` that does *not* look`main()`, it looks like a function called `DisplayList`

Comment: @RonyCohen The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You may want to use `std::map<Item, int>` rather than `std::set`.  The map will allow you to *associate* a count with an item.

Comment: I debug the problem I that in the debug the increase of count work but I don't know why I don't see this on the screen

Comment: `SpecificItem.setCount(...)` sets the count of the by-value parameter you passed to `addItem` (which is summarily destroyed on function exit). It has nothing to do with the items held by the customer, thus their item count remains the same.  Use the iterator.

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you explain a little more. I don't understand

Comment: Where is `DisplayList` called?  At some point you need to convert between `std::set` and array.  The `DisplayList` takes an array, but the `Customer` has a `std::set`.  The `std::set` only allows for one kind of item, no multiple quanitites.